# Django 3.2 how to redirect 404 to homepage

Tags: python, django

I did find a number of answers about 404 redirect for Django but mostly are referring to an older version of Django.

Here is what I have in Django 3.2.6
DEBUG is set to False to trigger the 404 behaviour

urls.py

```
 handler404 = views.view_404
```

views.py

```
 def view_404(request, exception=None):
     return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

No error in runserver but a 404 page still returns "Not Found

The requested resource was not found on this server.".

Comment: As mentioned in [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#handler404) `If you implement a custom view, be sure it accepts request and exception arguments and returns an HttpResponseNotFound.`

Comment: @Prakhar  where should I add this ? I am confused as the docs don't really discuss my case (redirect to homepage). Which is interesting since I think that many users would like this behaviour :)

Comment: This piece of code `handler404 = views.view_404` must be in the site urls.py file, not in the application urls.py.

Comment: @May.D ah wonderful feel free to write a quick reply. Now all works :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**urls.py**

```py
handler404 = 'myappname.views.view_404'
```

**views.py**

```py
 def view_404(request, exception=None):
      return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

Note that to display a custom template you can simply create a template with named `404.html` in your main templates directory.
For clarifications you can read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/views/).

Comment: thanks for the reply, the question is about redirect to the homepage so the 404.html is not really needed for a redirect

Comment: @devnull No problem for the answer. I know that overriding the model is not useful in your case, but I added that note because maybe some readers don't need to create a custom view but only a template.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that you defined your `handler404` in your app `urls.py` file.

You need to move it to the project `urls.py` file to get it working.